# How to getting selected option value with another table in laravel?

Tags: html, laravel

```
<select class="custom-select rounded-0" id="exampleSelectRounded0" name="kode_poli">
@foreach ($polikliniks as $poliklinik)
<option value="{{$poliklinik->id}}">{{$poliklinik->kode_poli}} | {{$poliklinik->nama_poli}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

My select option value will return a first id of poliklinik table

How to set select option 'selected' with another value in poliklinik table with my selected value when i insert before?

Comment: Are you on edit page where you want to show saved value should be selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write an option with the selected id as the value and selected name in between the option tag

```
<select class="custom-select rounded-0" id="exampleSelectRounded0" name="kode_poli">
<option value="{{$selected->id}}">{{$selected->kode_poli}}</option>
@foreach ($polikliniks as $poliklinik)
<option value="{{$poliklinik->id}}">{{$poliklinik->kode_poli}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

> Note: substitute the selected with the model you used in saving it